# How to wait for a reducer to sync to disk in redux-persist

Tags: redux, redux-persist

How to make redux-persist to guarantee that an action has been saved to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `await persistor.flush()`

https://nicedoc.io/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md#type-persistor

It's a promise and it should flush all the pending changes to disk.